# How to get data from a partial view ViewModel in to the main ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am creating a POC application using ASP.net MVC5. I want to have a top level view model that contains the data for all the view models in the partial views. However when I submit the form it doesn't pass data in the models to the top level which I somewhat expected but didn't want to happen.

View models

```C#
public class InvoiceViewModel
{
    public InvoiceInfo InvoiceInfo { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceInfo
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DateRaised { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public int InvoiceNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
    public Currency InvoiceCurrency { get; set; }
}
```

Form submit function

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateInvoice(InvoiceInfo vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        vm.FromDate = vm.ToDate;
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

Main razer view using 'InvoiceViewModel'

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateInvoice", "Invoice", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.Partial("_InvoiceInfo", Model.InvoiceInfo)

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Partial view '_InvoiceInfo'

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>InvoiceInfo</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateRaised, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateRaised, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateRaised, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InvoiceNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InvoiceNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InvoiceNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
ETC...
```

So When I click submit I would expect the InvoiceInfo object to be within the InvoiceViewModel object with all the relevant data. This might not be possible but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should use `InvoiceViewModel` for `CreateInvoice` method because you submit form in view that used `InvoiceViewModel` then if you create form tag in partial and submit it your code is right.

Comment: I see what your getting at here but I want to just submit the top level form for this functionality

Answer (score 0):

its easier to do `InvoiceInfo : InvoiceViewModel`.
Razor `@model InvoiceViewModel` in this way you have all properties, from both models.

Comment: Inheritance won't work here as it will make processing down the line very difficult as I need it to be structured in to an XML document.

Comment: Inheritance works, but can be difficult management all the data.. You can use the property ViewBag.